# div Side by side with a twist

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to make divs side by side?

I want the layout

```
------------
|Header div|
------------
|  |       |
|ul|iframe |
|  |       |
```

But if the iframe is visible:hidden/collapsed the `<ul>` will take all the space

```
------------
|Header div|
------------
|          |
|ul        |
|          |
```

If I make the ul float left, then the ul will not have width:auto
and if I make the iframe position:absolute the ul will always exapand thru the entire site.

All the sites that shows this use ul with a margin. But then the ul will have the margin if the iframe isnt there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I solved it. By setting overflow:auto on the ul element!


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>Header</div>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" style="width:20%;float:right">
</iframe>
<ul style="overflow: auto;">
  <li style="border: solid 1px Yellow;margin: 5px;">Left column / main column</li>
  <li style="border: solid 1px Yellow;margin: 5px;">A list</li>
  <li style="border: solid 1px Yellow;margin: 5px;">of things</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you float the `iframe` to the right of the `ul`, then the content of the `ul` will be able to fill the full width when it is removed (or the `display` style is set to `none`). Since altering the `visibility` style does not affect layout, changing that will accomplish nothing.

```
<div>Header</div>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" style="width:80%;float:right">
</iframe>
<ul>
  <li>Left column / main column</li>
  <li>A list</li>
  <li>of things</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will almost make it work. but the problem is that the ul is 100% of the site even when the iframe is on the site.
<ul style="background-color: Yellow;">
The yellow take width: 100%

Comment: Yes. But the content of the ul will not take up the full width.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the iframe in a div to handle the iframe position. Reduce the div's padding to 0.